# Who first used the phrase "Deflationary Theory of Truth"?

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy, truth, frege

[SEP's history of the deflationary theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/#HisDef) does not explain the origins of the term Deflationary, but does point to the first people who "explicitly defended it".

> The deflationary theory has been one of the most popular approaches to
> truth in the twentieth century, having received explicit defense by
> Frege, Ramsey, Ayer, and Quine, as well as sympathetic treatment from
> many others. (According to Dummett 1959, the view originates with
> Frege.) The following passages all contain recognizable versions of
> the doctrine, though they differ on points of detail.

(Note: none of the passages quoted afterwards use the word "deflationary")

Who first said used phrase "deflationary theory of truth"? Was it Frege?

Comment: I do not think Frege and other forerunners... Maybe form 1970-80s: Field, Horwich,...

Comment: don't know. I would guess Donald Davidson.

Comment: A quite early one: H. Field, The Deflationary Conception of Truth (1986)

Comment: It seems that the different "variants" are: Redundancy theory (Ramsey, 1928), Disquotational theory (Quine, 1970), Deflationary theory (Field, 1986).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, none of those authors used the label, not Frege, not Ramsey, not Quine, and not even Dummett writing about Frege. One can see on the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deflationary+theory+of+truth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeflationary%20theory%20of%20truth%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdeflationary%20theory%20of%20truth%3B%2Cc0) how the term "deflationary theory of truth" first appears in 1986 and picks up exponentially from there. The source is not too far to find, it is [Hartry Field's The Deflationary Conception of Truth](https://philpapers.org/rec/FIETDC) published in Fact, Science and Value volume, where he ascribed the doctrine to a number of past authors. He contrasted it to "inflationary" conceptions, one of which he himself defended back in 1970s, see [Gupta, Field on the Concept of Truth](http://www.philosophy.pitt.edu/sites/default/files/gupta/pdf/FieldontheConceptofTruth.pdf). Although Field preferred "conception" to "theory", Putnam felt otherwise. So much so that in a citation in [Representation and Reality, ch. 5 (1988)](https://philpapers.org/rec/PUTRAR) he even "renamed" Field's 1986 essay into Deflationary Theories of Truth.

I should mention that there is non-technical use of "deflationary truth" that predates Field's appropriation, see e.g. [Rajan's book on Eliot's poetry, p.78 (1976)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Overwhelming_Question/EZpaAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0):"*The deflationary truth is that no potential poem came into Eliot's mind and that the poem which eventually shaped itself round the occasion was a by - product of his dramatic interests*".